# Initialize a slideshow with JavaScript onload function

Tags: javascript, html

I am initializing a slideshow in my page and I want it to be executed after the page is completely loaded.

I'm using onload function with JavaScript to do that.

Now my problem is components of slideshow (images) which are in my body tag. 
I don't know how to control them with onload function. as you know before the slideshow starts, images form a Queue from top to down of the page.

To understand my purpose better, suppose that I have an image in my body tag like this and I don't want it to be shown before every component of the page ( even JavaScript functions including audio and slideshow) isn't loaded completely.

Here is a part of my code, JavaScript includes a slideshow plus an audio.
Thank you

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 window.onload = a;

 function a() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slideshow').cycle({

x:'curtainX', 
sync:  false,
});
});

 setTimeout(plus1,9000);
function plus1() { 

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slideshow').cycle('pause');
});
}
var music = new Audio("archive.mp3");
music.play(); 

}
</script>
.
.
.
 <body>
  <div id="slideshow">
      <p><img src="10.png" width="420" height="420"/></p>
      <p><img src="9.png" width="420" height="420"/></p>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only specific one time `document.ready()`.
Whe you enter inside `document.ready()` the dom element are ready and window are loaded already
you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#slideshow').show();
     $('#slideshow').cycle({
          x:'curtainX', 
          sync:  false,
     });

    setTimeout(plus1,9000);
    function plus1() { 
          $('#slideshow').cycle('pause');
    } 
    var music = new Audio("archive.mp3"); music.play();  
 });
```

And this is html

```
<body>
  <div id="slideshow" style="display:none;">
      <p><img src="10.png" width="420" height="420"/></p>
      <p><img src="9.png" width="420" height="420"/></p>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: thank you . i will use that . but my problem is with images . any suggestion about that ?

Comment: I checked it , but when I display the images as none , the slideshow disappears too . what's wrong with it?

any idea?
thanks

Comment: You haven't to make display none to The Image in my example. If you have other code update your question and i will try to find the problem. But is another question that you have to open. This question have already an answer. I advise you to create a new question with new problem :-) @Nima